# How take path in request.FILE['file'] to put it for download link

Tags: python, django, httprequest

I  create foo to upload files to Django models, its InMemoryUpload object. and how can I collect the full path to download link?

my models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    """Class for uplaoded files. colect file and description
    working with analog form
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    file_path = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    hash_size = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id},{self.file_path},{self.hash_size}"

    def get_hash(file: object) -> str:
        md = hashlib.md5()
        # with open(file, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(4096), b""):
            md.update(chunk)
        return md.hexdigest()
```

my views.py

```
def model_form_upload_1(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    ''' view handling this form will receive the file data in
:attr:`request.FILES <django.http.HttpRequest.FILES>`'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload = request.FILES['file']
        path = upload.chunks()
        print(path)
        hash_tuple = ()
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(upload.size)
            if get_file_size(upload):
                hash = Document.get_hash(upload)
                hash_list = [x for x in Document.objects.all().values_list('hash_size')]
                hash_tuple += (hash,)
                if hash_tuple not in hash_list:
                    Document.objects.create(
                        file_path=request.GET.get(upload),
                        hash_size=hash)
                else:
                    return HttpResponseBadRequest("file bigger tha 300mb")
            return redirect("view")
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Form invalid")
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(
            request=request,
            template_name='model_form_upload.html',
            context={'form': form})
        return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html')
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html')
```

*download foo*

```
def simple_view(request):
    in_memory_file_obj = request.FILES["file"]
    FileSystemStorage(location="/tmp").save(in_memory_file_obj.name,
                                            in_memory_file_obj)
    return HttpResponse("Success")
```

my template.py

```
    <tr>
        <td>{{document.id}}</td>
        <td>{{document.file_path}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ document.file_path }}">download</a></td>
        <td>{{document.hash_size}}</td>
    </tr>
```

before I tried to take request.open(file) but it's actually not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in settings.py. As described in the official documents, by default the uploaded files will be saved from `MEDIA_ROOT`.

For example, suppose you have the following config in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/mysite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then you have to remove `location="/tmp"` from `FileSystemStorage` (because by default `location` is set to `MEDIA_ROOT`).

And add [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) to URLconf to serve static files with Django:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So, `my_file.png` will be served by the following URL:

`[IP or domain]/media/my_file.png`

This is only for development env (`DEBUG =True`). In production, files should be served with web servers like `Nginx`.